# c# Best place to store strings for use in web pages

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I am creating my first .net website.

A lot of pages have code enhanced strings in the pages, like this:

```
string.Format("{0} Reviews", _store.Name);
```

Whilst this on it's own isn't unwieldly some pages have many string that are long, and makes the code page cumbersome.

I know that you can use resource files to store strings but that doesn't take into account the programatical inserts into the string.

Has anyone got any techniques for handling this a little better?

UPDATE

Wow, thanks for the prompt any plentiful responses guys. I'll take a look through them all to see which suits best.

Comment: Please comment of "doesn't take into account the programatical inserts into the string." - not sure how it is related to storing strings in resources.

Comment: Use application cache to store it

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - mean dynamically inserting into the string, as per string.Format()

Comment: I get where you want to use them, but still not clear what problem you see with string obtained from resource files... strings are strings no matter how you get them... Constant strings would also be not suitable as format strings for "programatical inserts into the string" than...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Application Settings or create Resourcefiles for the different cultures and languages you want to provide.

- [MSDN - ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Codeproject- An Easy Introduction to Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15991/An-Easy-Introduction-to-Localization-in-ASP-NET-2)
- [MSDN - Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Codeproject - Globalization and localization demystified in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15313/Globalization-and-localization-demystified-in-ASP)
- [Scott Hanselman - Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript and jQuery - Part 1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)
- [MSDN - Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: An update to a later version of the Application Settings information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/a65txexh(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 2):

I would just store

```
"{0} Reviews"
```

in the resource file and give it a sensible name, e.g. ReviewsWithStoreNameParam

Answer (score 1):

You can use resource files and add programmatical inserts.

E.g. you can put `"{0} Reviews"` in a resource file.

Answer (score 1):

I use resources dinamically:

```
string.Format(GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResources", "Label_Reviews").ToString(), _store.Name);
```

And in the MyResources.resx:

```
Label_Reviews --> "{0} Reviews"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two methods :-

> 1).You could build long winded strings in a config file.
>
> 2).You could store pre-determined text strings in an XML file.

Hope this is of use.

Answer (score 0):

I use config files for this kind of purposes. You can easily modify them even when the application is running.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="1" value="TestString" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* store the programatical inserts within your string in the resource file.

Simply store the string like this:

```
Name             | Value
-----------------+-------------------
reviews          | {0} Reviews
```

And call it like this (assuming your resource file is named the default `Resource1.resx`)

```
string.Format(Resource1.reviews, _store.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the aspx.cs file, (server side) create the string with public

```
public string reviews;
```

After you doing your logic, you set the value:

```
reviews = string.Format("{0} Reviews", _store.Name);
```

So, your var is public, you can use the string reviews in your aspx file

```
<%= reviews %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Global.asax file

Declare static HashTable in Global.asax like this:

```
public static Hashtable LabelResource = null;
```

You can load this hash table either from Database or XML file or simple text file at either Application_OnStart or Session_Start

And you can use this variable across your application (in your aspx page) like:

```
Global.LabelResource["ReviewString1"].ToString()
```